# How to use GitHub Branch as a paramater for Azure DevOps Pipelines?

Tags: azure, github, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have a test and a production environment. I use GitHub branches for deployments. Artifacts on the development branch should be deployed to the development environment and production artefacts on production.

One way to achieve this is to have a different azure-pipeline.yml file on develop and master.

```
      - task: AzureFileCopy@4
        displayName: 'copy spark jobs'
        inputs:
          sourcePath: $(workingDirectory)/transformed
          azureSubscription: developSubscription
          destination: azureBlob
          storage: developStorageAccount
          containerName: sourcecode
          blobPrefix: myBlob
          resourceGroup: developmentSourceGroup
```

I would replace on the master branch the identifiers for azureSubscription, resourceGroup, and storage on prod. But this would also mean that with every merge, I risk overwriting the production settings with the development settings.

So I wonder if there is a way to define which setting to take depending on the branch which is used for deployment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a good approach. What you should try instead is to have only one branch and use seprate stages for test and production environment. And for production stages use filter to allow deployment just from master branch. But on test you should do deploment from develop and master too. This is because you need to test before go to production. Imagein you will not notice a issue on merging code to master branch and then you will get another chance to detect it testing on test enivronment.

It could be like

```
stages:
- stage: Test
  displayName: Test
  condition: and(succeeded(), or(eq(variables['build.sourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/master'),eq(variables['build.sourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/develop'), eq(variables['Build.Reason'], 'PullRequest'), eq(variables['Build.Reason'], 'Manual')))
  jobs:
  - deployment: Test
    displayName: Test
    environment: Test
    workspace:
      clean: all
    strategy:
      runOnce:
        deploy:
          steps:
          - task: AzureFileCopy@4
            displayName: 'copy spark jobs'
            inputs:
              sourcePath: $(workingDirectory)/transformed
              azureSubscription: developSubscription
              destination: azureBlob
              storage: developStorageAccount
              containerName: sourcecode
              blobPrefix: myBlob
              resourceGroup: developmentSourceGroup

- stage: Production
  displayName: Production
  condition: and(succeeded(), eq(variables['build.sourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/master'))
  jobs:
  - deployment: Production
    displayName: Production
    environment: Production
    workspace:
      clean: all
    strategy:
      runOnce:
        deploy:
          steps:
          - task: AzureFileCopy@4
            displayName: 'copy spark jobs'
            inputs:
              sourcePath: $(workingDirectory)/transformed
              azureSubscription: productionSubscription
              destination: azureBlob
              storage: productionStorageAccount
              containerName: sourcecode
              blobPrefix: myBlob
              resourceGroup: productionSourceGroup
```

please notice that I used deployment job which will provide you for instance approvals if you configure them.